# realm.objects(databaseName) alway return result of type Array but I am looking for something which return object not Array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, realm, realm-mobile-platform

My schemas are following

```
const groupsettings = {
    name: 'groupsettings',
    properties: {
        id:'string?',
        groupsettings: 'groupsetting[]',
    }
}

const groupsetting = {
    name: 'groupsetting',
    primaryKey: '_id',
    properties: {
        _id: 'string',
        title: 'string',
        forms: 'forlderForms[]',
        sequence: 'int',
    }
}
```

Now I am fetching groupsettings schema with realm.objects('groupsettings) and it return data in array form while I need in form of object. is it possible?

i.e it return something like this `[{"groupsettings": [Array], "id": null}]` while I want  `{"groupsettings": [Array], "id": null}`

Comment: can you edit your question to make it more readable? Perhaps copy and paste your Realm objects as text (no images) and format the code

Comment: @Jay Done can you please provide solution if you have Thanks.

Comment: This `realm.objects('groupsettings)` does not return an array, it returns a Results object  which contains all of the Realm objects of which you requested. That's how Realm works. If you want a specific object, you need to query for that object using a filter or read it directly by its primary key. The question needs further clarification as to what object you want to return and the code you've attempted to get that object.

Comment: realm.objects('groupsettings) only have one object then why it return in form of array like this  [{"groupsettings": [Array], "id": null}]. As of now what I have to do  is result[0]. groupsettings but what I want is result. groupsettings directly. groupsettings schema always have only item in it no more then that.

Comment: Are you asking why telling something that it's an array returns as an array? [{"groupsettings": [**Array**], "id": null}]? To read realm objects into a results, do this `var dogResults = realm.objects('Dogs')`